# My 2011 Equinox check engine light came on. I had it coded - read P0013

Tags: chevrolet, equinox, p0013

How do I replace the cam shaft position switch and/or actuator?

Comment: Before you go replacing your sensor and/or actuator, you need to determine if that is actually the issue. There are a few other things you need to check beforehand. [Please read this page](http://www.engine-codes.com/p0013_chevrolet.html) for understanding of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to remove the airbox and the plastic cover over the valve cover to gain access to the CPS and actuator.

The cam position sensor and actuator are located on the top of your valve cover to the left of the number 1 spark plug.

From there you can remove the wires to the CPS and the actuator and have access to remove and replace them.